# I can't enter numbers in a tuple and find their average value. /ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'PY_VAR0'/

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to add numbers to an array and then find their average, but I definitely can't.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x100')

v41 = IntVar()
avg_time_bars = []

def bars1_1_1_4():
    avg_time_bars.append(str(v41))
    L = [float(n) for n in avg_time_bars if n]
    r_bars1_1_1_4 = sum(L) / len(L) if L else '-'
    print(v41.get())
    print(list(avg_time_bars))
    print(r_bars1_1_1_4)

b_bars1_1_1_4 = Button(root, text='Add', command=bars1_1_1_4)
b_bars1_1_1_4.grid(row=16, column=3)

e_bars1_1_1_4 = Entry(root, textvariable=v41)
e_bars1_1_1_4.grid(row=16, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `avg_time_bars.append(str( v41) )` to `avg_time_bars.append( v41.get())`

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating `str(v41)`, where `v41` is an `IntVar()`, will simply give you the string representation of the `IntVar` *wrapper* variable (rather than that of its *content*).

If you want the string representation of its content, you will need `str(v41.get())`. See the following transcript to confirm this:

```py
pax:/mnt/c/Users/Pax/Documents/wsl> python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26)
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tkinter

>>> root = tkinter.Tk()

>>> v41 = tkinter.IntVar()

>>> v41.set(12345)

>>> str(v41)
'PY_VAR0'

>>> str(v41.get())
'12345'
```

Hence the first line of your `bars1_1_1_4()` function should probably be:

```py
avg_time_bars.append(str(v41.get()))
```

Comment: thank you very much, it worked :).  /avg_time_bars.append(str(v41.get()))/